# User is always unathorized in quickblox

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am able to login successfully in QuickBlox but [[serviceManager instance]isAuthorized] is always return NO.

What is the issue.?
Please Help.

Comment: How are you doing Quickblox login? (which method).

Comment: [[serviceManager instance]isAuthorized] is QMServices addiction, so you should login using QMServices methods and not QBRequest.